# Responsive Images - Add srcset attributes to custom Images Function

Tags: images, responsive

When I use   `get_the_post_thumbnail( NULL, 'entry-fullwidth', NULL );` wordpress automatically outputs the `srcset` data like these:

```
<img 
    width="1000" 
    height="625" 
    src="https://x.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/photo.jpg" 
    class="attachment-entry-fullwidth size-entry-fullwidth wp-post-image" 
    alt="" 
    srcset="
        https://x.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/photo.jpg 1000w, 
        https://x.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/photo-768x480.jpg 768w" 
    sizes="
        (max-width: 767px) 95vw, 
        (max-width: 979px) 80vw, 1200px
">
```

Is there a native wordpress function or another way to output srcset data for images in my custom function below?

```
function photo_shortcode($atts){
   extract(shortcode_atts(array(
      'no' => 1,
   ), $atts));

   $no     = ( $no       != ''     ) ? $no : 1;
   $images = get_field('fl_gallery');
   $image  = $images[$no];

if ($image) {
   $credit = get_field('fl_credit', $image['id']);
   return '<div class="kalim"><img title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( sprintf( the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ) . '" src="' . $image['url'] . '" /><div class="kalca">' . $image['caption'] . '</div>' . (!empty($credit) ? '<div class="kalcr">Credit:' . $credit . '</div></div>': '' ) ;
 }

}

add_shortcode('photo', 'photo_shortcode');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think [`wp_get_attachment_srcset()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_srcset/) is what you are looking for.

```
$srcset = wp_get_attachment_image_srcset( $image['id'], array( 100, 100 ) );
```

Now you can escape the HTML and use it in your code.

```
<img src="PATH HERE" srcset="<?php echo esc_attr( $srcset ); ?>">
```

Comment: ok but that is the array( 100, 100 ) used for? The answer should return the url for the 768x400 size ?

Comment: That was just an example. You can use any size you wish, or even pass a size slug such as `medium` or `large`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look of this article 
https://alexwright.net/web-design-secrets/responsive-images-wordpress/

It explains how srcset and responsive images work in Wordpress.